# Restrict user from run JAR/Python file

Tags: windows-10, python, java

I want to prevent user from run JAR file or Python file in windows 10/8/7. I used applocker to prevent run exe files / ps1 scripts but can't restrict JAR/Python files. I can't remove the JAVA or Python from the machine so this is not option for me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you lock down (for instance) java.exe using NTFS security?  I am too lazy to try it but I bet that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If they are on Windows Pro or Enterprise you can use the policy editor.

Be aware that this task requires administrative rights and a server computer.

full step by step instructions can be found [here.](https://www.file-extensions.org/article/how-to-restrict-certain-file-types-in-windows-group-policy)